# Multiple XML attributes

Tags: sql-server, xml, resultset

I want to produce an XML file with the following format:

```
<ProData>
    <DataSet Name="ABCD">
        <Data DataElement="AAA" Value="10"/>
        <Data DataElement="BBB" Value="20"/>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="EFGH">
        <Data DataElement="CCC" Value="NAME"/>
        <Data DataElement="DDD" Value="SURNAME"/>
    </DataSet>
</ProData>
```

Each row from MyTable should have a ProData record in the XML produced.
My Table is this

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    [CustomerNumber] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [AAA_Value] Int NOT NULL,
    [BBB_Value] Int NOT NULL,
    [Name]     [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL 
)



INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([CustomerNumber], [AAA_Value], [BBB_Value], [Name], [Surname]) VALUES (N'123456', 10, 20, N'Phoebe', N'Buffay')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([CustomerNumber], [AAA_Value], [BBB_Value], [Name], [Surname]) VALUES (N'234567', 30, 40, N'Ross', N'Geller')
```

So a desired output should be:

```
<ProData>
    <DataSet Name="ABCD">
        <Data DataElement="AAA" Value="10"/>
        <Data DataElement="BBB" Value="20"/>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="EFGH">
        <Data DataElement="CCC" Value="Phoebe"/>
        <Data DataElement="DDD" Value="Buffay"/>
    </DataSet>
</ProData>
<ProData>
    <DataSet Name="ABCD">
        <Data DataElement="AAA" Value="30"/>
        <Data DataElement="BBB" Value="40"/>
    </DataSet>
    <DataSet Name="EFGH">
        <Data DataElement="CCC" Value="Ross"/>
        <Data DataElement="DDD" Value="Geller"/>
    </DataSet>
</ProData>
```

I am using a `FOR XML PATH` query to retrieve my `XML` file but I can not succeed in retrieving multiple nested elements, due to the following error:

> The same attribute cannot be generated more than once on the same XML
>   tag.

My query is the following:

```
(SELECT   
    blah,  
     'AAA'      as 'Common/Data/ProData/DataSet/Data/@DataElement',
    AAA_Value   AS 'Common/ApplicationData/ProData/DataSet/Data/@Value'     ,       
    'BBB'       as 'Common/Data/ProData/DataSet/Data/@DataElement' ,             
    BBB_Value   as 'Common/Data/ProData/DataSet/Data/@Value', 
    blah
FROM MyTable
FOR XML PATH('Notification'),ROOT('NotificationsList'),              
TYPE)
FOR XML PATH ('NotificationFile')
```

I have managed to get the desired result by "forcing" the resultset with a nested query like this:

```
(SELECT   blah,  
    (SELECT 
        (SELECT
            (SELECT 'AAA' AS 'Data/@DataElement' ,
                    AAA_Value   AS 'Data/@Value' 
                    FROM MyTable WHERE CONDITION
                    FOR xml path(''),   TYPE),

            (SELECT 'BBB' AS 'Data/@DataElement' ,
                    BBB_Value   AS 'Data/@Value' 
                    FROM MyTable WHERE CONDITION
                    FOR xml path(''),   TYPE),

            FOR xml path('DataSet'), TYPE)
            FOR xml path('ProData'), TYPE ) ,
    blah
    FROM MyTable
    FOR XML PATH('Notification'),ROOT('NotificationsList'),              
    TYPE      )
FOR XML PATH ('NotificationFile')
```

I am pretty sure this is a terrible way to do it, but I can not seem to manage a better way for it.

Comment: how about providing us with the example data that you used so we can try to assist?

Comment: I provided the table's layout. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, no, you did not provide your table's layout, just some column names... Please provide a real table definition (with types) and some rows of sample data together with the expected output fitting to this data...

Comment: You are right! I updated the question once again

Comment: And I've voted it up already :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've clearified your needs, I think it's this what you want

--Your table

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    [CustomerNumber] [nvarchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [AAA_Value] Int NOT NULL,
    [BBB_Value] Int NOT NULL,
    [Name]     [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL 
)
```

--Test data

```
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([CustomerNumber], [AAA_Value], [BBB_Value], [Name], [Surname]) 
VALUES (N'123456', 10, 20, N'Phoebe', N'Buffay')
INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] ([CustomerNumber], [AAA_Value], [BBB_Value], [Name], [Surname]) 
VALUES (N'234567', 30, 40, N'Ross', N'Geller');

GO
```

--The query

```
SELECT 
 (
    SELECT 'ABCD' AS [@Name]
          ,'AAA' AS [Data/@DataElement]
          ,AAA_Value AS [Data/@Value]
          ,''
          ,'BBB' AS [Data/@DataElement]
          ,BBB_Value AS [Data/@Value]
    FOR XML PATH('DataSet'),TYPE
 )
 ,''
 ,(
    SELECT 'EFGH' AS [@Name]
          ,'CCC' AS [Data/@DataElement]
          ,Name AS [Data/@Value]
          ,''
          ,'DDD' AS [Data/@DataElement]
          ,Surname AS [Data/@Value]
    FOR XML PATH('DataSet'),TYPE
 )
FROM MyTable
FOR XML PATH('ProData')
GO
```

--Clean up **attention with real data!!!**

```
--DROP TABLE MyTable;
```

The result

```
<ProData>
  <DataSet Name="ABCD">
    <Data DataElement="AAA" Value="10" />
    <Data DataElement="BBB" Value="20" />
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet Name="EFGH">
    <Data DataElement="CCC" Value="Phoebe" />
    <Data DataElement="DDD" Value="Buffay" />
  </DataSet>
</ProData>
<ProData>
  <DataSet Name="ABCD">
    <Data DataElement="AAA" Value="30" />
    <Data DataElement="BBB" Value="40" />
  </DataSet>
  <DataSet Name="EFGH">
    <Data DataElement="CCC" Value="Ross" />
    <Data DataElement="DDD" Value="Geller" />
  </DataSet>
</ProData>
```

One note: the empty columns in between (`,''`) tell the engine to start a new element. This will avoid the error you've got...

Comment: I should have cleared out that "ABCD", "AAA", "BBB", "EFGH", "CCC", "DDD" are all hardcoded values and only the Values are coming from the table. I will try to tweak your answer, as it looks much more simpler than mine, to see what I can do. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot Shnugo! That was exactly what I wanted.